# Reference equals returns false if object2 = object1

Tags: c#, equality

I have this piece of code:

```
Rect a = new Rect(0, 0, 4, 4);
Rect b = new Rect(0, 0, 4, 4);
print(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)); //prints false
print(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, a)); //prints false
b = a;
print(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b)); //prints false
```

I want to be able to determine if the reference is the same object in memory, so the same reference to the object. So the first print should return `false` and the 2nd print should return `true`. The `Rect` is from the Unity engine but I could wrap it in my own class and override equals if that needs to be done. Yet I would expect line 6 to print `true` since `a = b` would point both variables to the same reference.

Comment: Is `Rect` a value type? Both arguments will be boxed in the call to `ReferenceEquals` and will always return `false` in that case.

Comment: try reading the [MSDN Documentation on Test for Reference Equality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183759.aspx)

Comment: Guys, this is a million-times duplicate.  It's so easy to google

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Rect`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect.html) seems to be a struct, not a reference type.
`ReferenceEquals` [will always return `false` for structs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2008/03/18/object-referenceequalsvaluevar-valuevar-will-always-return-false/), because of boxing.